# What should be chosen as country of visit if I take travel insurance for Asian Countries

Tags: international-travel, insurance

I am planning to visit a few highly-developed countries in Asia, such as Japan, South Korea, and so on.

While buying travel insurance there was an option to choose the country of visit. In that section, I can give multiple countries name or directly choose Asia.

What shall I choose?

1. Japan, Korea
2. Asia

Comment: Technically "Asia" is considered a Continent not a Country

Comment: Choose the cheapest?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Asia is a lot bigger than the two countries you mention, running from the Mediterranean Sea to Japan and from the Arctic to the south of Indonesia.

If you only visit two countries and can select just those countries it might be best to select the countries you actually plan to visit.

But if you plan to visit South Korea mention it as such, North Korea is a really different country.

In the insurance I usually buy I have three options, within my own country, the continent or the whole world, which makes the choice easy.
Do read if they have a description of 'Asia' so you can see whether that covers what you need and is cheaper than a series of countries you enter yourself.

Comment: I have not seen a continent option.  The choices that I am used to seeing are: whether or not US and Canada are covered and whether winter sports are covered.  Worldwide without US and Canada and without winter sports is usually good value.

Comment: In the UK you get 'Europe', possibly 'World ex US and Canada' and 'World inc US and Canada'. 'Europe' is cheaper because of the EHIC card meaning healthcare is free. The US and Canada option is more expensive due to America's insanely expensive healthcare.